# I am getting unexpected behavour of count() in map C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    map<int, int> nums_map;
    cout << nums_map.count(0) << endl;
    int a = nums_map[0];
    cout << nums_map.count(0) << endl;
    cout << nums_map[0];
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
0
1
0

It makes no sense to me at least, why the line:

```
int a = nums_map[0];
```

is increasing the value of count by 1, also the `nums_map.empty()` = 0 at the same time.

Comment: [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) value-initializes an element at that key if one doesn't exist. That's what allows you to initialize `a` at all.

Answer (score 4):

Because `std::map::operator[]` works in a slightly weird way. From [the documentation on `std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

So if the key doesn't exist, it creates a new pair. That's exactly what's happening here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    map<int, int> nums_map;            // nums_map == {}
    cout << nums_map.count(0) << endl; // 0, because the map is empty
    int a = nums_map[0];               /* a new key/value pair of {0, 0} is
                                          created and a is set to nums_map[0],
                                          which is 0 */
    cout << nums_map.count(0) << endl; // Since there is one key 0 now, this shows 1
    cout << nums_map[0];               // As shown previously, nums_map[0] is 0
    return 0;
}
```